# SQLite работа с двумя и более таблицами

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Добрый день подскажите как работать с 2 таблицами? и когда нужно открывать и закрывать базу данных. Нашел пример в интернете сделал как нужно мне:

```
 public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public  static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
   public  static final String  DATABASE_NAME="fitnes";
   public  static final String  TABLE_CONTACTS="food";
    public  static final String  TABLE_CONTACTS_2="time";

   public  static final String  KEY_ID="_id";//ид
   public  static final String  KEY_NAME="name";//название (гречка, молоко, мясо)
   public  static final String  KEY_SQUIRRELS ="Squirrels";//кол-во белка
   public  static final String  KEY_FAT ="Fat";//кол-во жиров
   public  static final String  KEY_CARBOHYDRATES ="Carbohydrates";//кол-во углеводы
   public  static final String  KEY_CALORIES ="Calories";//кол_во калорий

    public  static final String  KEY_TIME="time";//ид
    public  static final String  KEY_TYPE="typeFood";//ид

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_SQUIRRELS + " integer," + KEY_FAT + " integer," + KEY_CARBOHYDRATES + " integer," + KEY_CALORIES + " integer" + ")");//Если таблицы не существует то мы ее создаем
            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS_2 + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + KEY_TIME + " numeric," + KEY_TYPE + " text" + ")");//Если таблицы не существует то мы ее создаем
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS_2);
        onCreate(db);//а тут обновляем таблицу
}
}
```

Теперь добавляю данные в таблицу:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                // SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//нужен для управления
                //ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();//нужен для добавления новых строк в таблицу выглядит как массив с именами столбцов и тд

                EditText NAME = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edNamePro);
                EditText SQUIRRELS = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edSQ);
                EditText FAT = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edFA);
                EditText CARBOHYDRATES = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edCAB);
                EditText CALORIES = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edCAL);

                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, NAME.getText().toString());
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_SQUIRRELS, SQUIRRELS.getText().toString());
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_FAT, FAT.getText().toString());
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_CARBOHYDRATES, CARBOHYDRATES.getText().toString());
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_CALORIES, CALORIES.getText().toString());
                database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
                dbHelper.close();//отключаемся от бд
                dlg.dismiss();
            }
```

И как я понял так я добавляю в другую :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {//сохраняем все позициии
            EditText time = (EditText) allEds.get(i).findViewById(R.id.ed_time);//берем время
            EditText type_food = (EditText) allEds.get(i).findViewById(R.id.buffer_food_select);//берем текст который хранится в буффере который скрыт от глаз
            /*buffer_text = buffer_text + "-" + time.getText().toString();
            buffer_text_food = buffer_text_food + "+" + type_food.getText().toString() + "/";*/
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TIME, time.getText().toString());
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TYPE, type_food.getText().toString());
        }
```

Теперь пытаюсь считать данные, но ничего не происходит:

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null,
                null, null, null);// ТУТ ПРОИСХОДИТ СОРТИРОВКА В ДАЛЬНЕЙШЕМ ПРИГОДИТСЯ ЗАПОМНИ
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
            int nameindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
            int proteindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_SQUIRRELS);
            int jirindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_FAT);
            int ygliindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_CARBOHYDRATES);
            int calorindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_CALORIES);
            do {
                Log.d("mLOg ", "ID=" + cursor.getInt(idindex) +

                        "NAME= " + cursor.getString(nameindex) +

                        "Белок= " + cursor.getInt(proteindex) +

                        "JIR= " + cursor.getInt(jirindex) +

                        "YGLI= " + cursor.getInt(ygliindex) +

                        "CALOR= " + cursor.getInt(calorindex));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Подскажите что я сделал не так, почему данные не считываются по нажатию и как правильно работать с 2 таблицами. Если можно небольшой приме, заранее спасибо

Comment: Не нужно закрывать соединение с БД, тем более вы это делаете не правильно! Пусть соединение будет открыто. И проверяйте что добавление записи в БД срабатывает, в logcat например вывод что метод onclick сработал.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev а как работать с 2 таблицами то?)

Comment: Вопрос, похоже, не имеет отношение у андроиду, вопрос по принципам работы с реляционными базами данных. Тут у вас описаны 2 таблицы, связанность которых совершенно не очевидна. Что вы имеете в виду под работой с 2 таблицами? Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: @Manro переделайте метод таким образом что бы он принимал в параметрах название таблицы, А чтение базы данных вынесите в SQLiteOpenHelper как вариант.